# Google Play Games login continuously popping up

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-play-services, sha1, google-play-games, google-play-console

I'm having an issue where the Google Play Games login pop-up is continuously prompting me to enter my login info. When I first enter it, it seems to register as I get the username UI graphic to appear. As soon as I transition to another screen though, it appears again...and then on the next screen again. Tapping my leaderboard button also just prompts me to login, but never transitions me to the GPG leaderboards/achievements.

I've reviewed old builds of my game and this issue is now occurring in them too. This leads me to believe it's more to do with GPG/credentials than anything code related. Plus, I've actually seen different results based on which test account I'm using.

Digging further, I noticed that my OAuth Client IDs that are listed in Google Play Console and the Google API Client ID section are different.(The first 12 digits are identical, but everything after the 'dash' is different.) Also, I noticed after retracing my steps (i.e. going through a GPG setup tutorial again) that I seemed to have a different SHA-1 as well. (Note: I ended up replacing the old SHA-1 listed in the API Client ID section with the new one to see if this refreshed anything. It didn't, and I forgot what the old SHA-1 listed was. If this could be part of the issue, I'd be curious how to change it back!)

I'm guessing the discrepancies between IDs/SHA-1s might be linked to this, but am not 100% sure. Has anyone run into this before and how did you resolve? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation about [certificate fingerprint](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting)?

Comment: Please state how you are connecting to GPGS: JavaScript, Android library, or from the Desktop Java lib? Share the code you are connecting with.